# Service Process - Ram Memory increases with time. How to fix it?

Tags: android, service

I am making an Android app which runs a simple Service in the background.
Nothing fancy but the service toasts a msg every 5 secs confirming that it is running in the background, even when the App activity is terminated.

But when i checked the task manager, i found that the process is utilizing 4MB of ram initially but later keeps on increasing with time.

I want to know that if there is any way i can stop the extra memory usage and keep it to a bare minimum, since i know i am not doing any heavy work in the background.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

P.S. I will post the service code below.

```
public class BgmService extends Service {

public Handler mHandler = new Handler();


public BgmService() {
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service has started!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    mHandler.post(mtask);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Killed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mtask);

}

public Runnable mtask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is Running!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mtask, 4000);

    }
};
```

}

Comment: kindly accept the answer if you have found the solution to your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PunK_l_RuLz told, your `Runnable` is getting created after every **4000** mili seconds. So, you can create a subclass of `Runnable` and use single object of this class for every `Toast` :

```
public class PostRunnable extends Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is Running!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 4000);

    }
}
```

Use above class like :

```
PostRunnable mRunnable;
if(mRunnable != null) {
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);
} else {
    mRunnable = new PostRunnable();
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! @Kushal 
Well I just implemented the method you mentioned above. But the problem still persist.
Actually now it increases for a while and then decreases by a little amount, and the process goes on.
Will this effect overall on my service performance?

Comment: Above code will decrease object creation multiple times, so it will decrease `RAM` usage, but if you want to check how your object size is increasing, you can use `Eclipse Memory Analyzer` MAT tool... If you can give full code, then i can help you more...

Answer (score 2):

you are calling the mTask from inside your mTask, every time a new object of Runnable is created and as your Service holds the reference of every runnable object created your memory goes on increasing. I think using a Timer with TimerTask might solve your problem. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the reply Punk.
well i implemented the new method as mention by you as well as @kushal.
but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a timer instead of a post delay?
It's odd though, I can't see why it would leak.

Comment: There are plenty of services which uses threads in the background. It shouldnt be a problem. But why the memory leakage?